# Catching SIGSEGV exception

Tags: c

I'm trying to use an exception handler to catch bad memory access but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing it. I tried registering it with sigaction but my handler isn't triggering..

Old code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
void handler(int sig)
{
    //exception should land here
    printf("caught exception");
    
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct sigaction act;
    
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handler;
    if(sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL)==-1){
        printf("Could not register handler");
    }else{
        printf("handler registered\n");
    }
    *(int*)0 = 0;//throw exception
    
    return 0;
}
```

And once inside the handler, how can I read the thread context registers?
I'm also on a MacOS so I'm unsure if there's any OS specific implementations.

Edit: New Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <ucontext.h>
void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *uc)
{
    (void) sig;
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, "Caught exception\n", 17);
    struct ucontext* mc = (struct ucontext*)uc;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct sigaction act;
    
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handler;
    if(sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL)==-1){
        printf("Could not register handler");
    }else{
        printf("handler registered\n");
    }
    raise (SIGSEGV);
    return 0;
}
```

When I included `ucontext.h` my compiler through this error

```
#else /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE */
#error The deprecated ucontext routines require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined
#endif /* _XOPEN_SOURCE */
```

Which I resolved by defining _XOPEN_SOURCE
But the compiler still doesn't know what ucontext is because I'm not getting any intellisence.. I might have to define the structure myself

Edit: Since I was on M1 I was compiling form ARM instead of x86_64 and ucontext and mcontext both have to use the 64bit variants..

Comment: In general there's not much you can do in a SIGSEGV handler. It usually happens because memory has been corrupted, and anything you try may be impacted by that corruption.

Comment: @Barmar I Do plan on actually handling the exception which does requiring manipulation of the text section to some degree

Comment: @teapot418 I tried placing the new line but still didn't trigger..is there a surefire way I can check the exception handler actually triggered? But also how can I read the registers in the handler?

Comment: @teapot418 Does your exception handler catch it?

Comment: I put the division by zero into the segv handler, the floating point exception is printed in the command line. But this is Linux, Mac may have some differences regarding signals.

Comment: You can not safely call `printf()` is a signal handler. Per [footnote 188 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allows for the calling of async-signal-safe functions in a signal handler](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03), but `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for the note, I wouldn't be using it in an actual implementation just merely to check if the handler did get called. I think the issue specifically in my code was using undefined behavior to trigger the exception.

Comment: You should do act.sa_sigaction = handler rather than act.sa_handler = handler.

Comment: You should use an alternate signal stack to catch the signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Undefined behavior is not reliable:**

Instead of relying on it, send a signal to the calling process with `raise()`:

```
raise (SIGSEGV);
```

So the code becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <unistd.h>

static void func (int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context);
{  
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, "Caught exception\n", 17);
    
    /* Restores the default handler. This is the only
     * portable use of signal().
     */
    signal (sig, SIG_DFL);
    raise (sig); 
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction act;

    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    /* Upon successful  completion, sigemptyset() shall return 0;
     * otherwise, it shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error.
     */
    if (sigemptyset (&act.sa_mask) == -1) {
        perror ("sigemptyset()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    act.sa_sigaction = handler;

    if (sigaction (SIGSEGV, &act, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not register handler\n");
    } else {
        fprintf (stderr, "handler registered\n");
    }

    raise (SIGSEGV);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output:**

```
handler registered
caught exception
```

---

**Print error messages to `stderr`:**

```
//printf ("Could not register handler\n"); 

fprintf (stderr, "Could not register handler.\n");
```

---

**Do not call async-signal-unsafe functions in signal handlers:**

Neither the C standard, nor the POSIX standard specifies `printf()` to be async-signal-safe, which means that it can not be safely called inside a signal handler.

Though,the POSIX standard does specify `write()` to be async-signal safe. So `printf()` should be replaced with it.

```
// printf ("Caught exception\n");

write (STDOUT_FILENO, "Caught exception\n", 17);
```

---

**Incorrect declaration of `handler()`:**

`void handler(int sig)` is not correct if `SA_SIGINFO` is set: "If `SA_SIGINFO` is set and the signal is caught, the signal-catching function shall be entered as: `void func(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context);`" - @AndrewHenle

```
//void func (int signo);

void func(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context);
```

---

**Assign `handler()` to the correct member:**

The sigaction structure is defined as something like:

```
struct sigaction {
     void (*sa_handler)(int);
     void (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
     sigset_t sa_mask;
     int sa_flags;
     void (*sa_restorer)(void);
};
```

When you use the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, you need to assign the signal handling function to `.sa_sigaction` instead of `.sa_handler`.

```
// act.sa_handler = handler;

sig.sa_sigaction = handler;
```

Comment: Ah thank you! That does catch the exception but now I'm struck with how to actually read the registers inside the handler..

Comment: [`void handler(int sig)` is not correct if SA_SIGINFO is set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/sigaction.html): "If `SA_SIGINFO` is set and the signal is caught, the signal-catching function shall be entered as: `void func(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context);`"

Comment: I didn't see or know that. I'll edit the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm wondering if I have to define the structure myself, I'm using XCode and including ucontext.h first throws a deprecation error which I resolved but I don't believe my compiler understands what ucontext is

Comment: @Kayla Do you have [`#include <ucontext.h>`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/ucontext.3.html)?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes I posted the updated code

Answer (score 1):

Your first question appears to have been answered so I won't get further into it. As for your second issue, Apple has its own definition of mcontext and ucontext specifically mcontext64 and ucontex64. Additionally, You're compiling for ARM64 instead of x86_64, hence why those registers would no longer exist in your compiled binary.

Go into your Build Settings->Architectures
Remove the standard architecture and replace it with x86_64, your handler should then be able to access the registers.

[image]

Comment: Yes. The open group page marks it as deprecated. *"The obsolescent functions getcontext(), makecontext(), and swapcontext() can be replaced using POSIX threads functions."* @Kayla If you've found a suitable solution, do post it as an answer.

Comment: @Haris The issue I was facing was compiling under ARM64 rather than x86_64 and then using the ucontext64 and mcontext64. Yours and Irelia's answer solved both problems